# VS Code not discovering Python unittests in WSL2 workspace

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, wsl-2

I am trying to run Unittests on VS Code using Python on **WSL2**. The tests are located in the folder `~/exercism/python/**/*_test.py`. Previously, I could run the tests from the Testing Tab but suddenly the tests stopped showing up.

I have tried deleting the .vscode-server files and doing a fresh installation of VS Code on my Windows machine, but that didn't help. I also updated the .vscode/settings.json file with the following:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./python",
        "-p",
        "**/*_test.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

However, the tests are still not showing up in the Testing Tab. I have also tried running the tests using the command `python -m unittest discover -v -s "./python" -p "**/*_test.py"`, but that only shows the message **Ran 0 tests in 0.000s OK**.

Can someone help me figure out why the tests are not showing up in the Testing Tab on VS Code?

Comment: is your folder supposed to be called "exercism" and not "exercise"? Or "exorcism" (oh dear...)

Comment: i dont see why you're even concerned with a folder name but to answer your question, no, it's not bound to be called "exercism". I use that to relate to "https://exercism.org/"